# Add-On Dev: Property Update Event (send variable name?)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

If I have a property group with a lot of properties, and I want to define a single update function that is called when any one of them changes, is there a way to send details about the variable being updated to that handler?

Something like..

```
def OnPropertyChange(self, context, identifier):
    property_that_changed = self[identifier]

...

class Props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    MyVal : BoolProperty(update=OnPropertyChange("MyVal"))
```

If this is not possible, is there any way to use a single handler like this without defining separated/specific handlers for every property? The only strategy I've come up with to get this working is by doing this, which is pretty terrible when you have a lot of them:

```
def GlobalPropertyChange(self, context, identifier):
    property_that_changed = self[identifier]

def PropChangeMyVal(self, context):
    GlobalPropertyChange( self, context, "MyVal" )

def PropChangeOtherVar(self, context):
    GlobalPropertyChange( self, context, "OtherVar" )

def PropChangeThirdThing(self, context):
    GlobalPropertyChange( self, context, "ThirdThing" )
```

I know it may be possible to define classes and functions dynamically in Python (I haven't tried it yet), which may be better than this in terms of maintenance. But I'm hoping there is a much simpler idea that I'm totally missing out on.

Appreciate any advice

Comment: You could use setters for all properties and in each setter function call the function that shall be called whenever a property changes.

Comment: I'm only aware of the setters that are defined and work like updaters. Is there a simpler way to define those? Some type of inlining maybe?